# angularjs create custom event directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple attribute-restricted directive like

```
app.directive('akMouseOver', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        mouseOver: '&akMouseOver'
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {

    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.bind('mouseover', function () {
            scope.mouseOver({ hValue: value });
        });
    }
}})
```

that I am calling on a simple HTML button as

```
<button ak-mouse-over='btnMouseOver('Win Win')' class='btn btn-primary'> Hello There !</button>
```

and my parent controller method is

```
$scope.btnMouseOver = function (hValue) {
    alert(hValue + 'Hello !!!');
}
```

Here, somehow, I am unable to pass a parameter to the parent method. If I make this implementation without parameter, it is working and I see `alert()`, if I hover the mouse over the button.

Looking for passing (a) parameter/s without adding additional attribute/directive/scope variable.

Comment: I will explain you seperate !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it should work & then it would alert with `Win Win Hello !!!` because you had hardcoded value of function level, even if you pass value from directive it will just pass the same.

While passing value from directive to registered function of isolated scope, you should have `btnMouseOver(hValue)`, because when you are calling `mouseOver` function of directive which will basically going to call `btnMouseOver` method registered on `ak-mouse-over` attribute.

At the time of passing value you need to have pass value to parent controller function in JSON kind of format like `{hValue: value}` where `hValue` will represent parameter of `btnMouseOver` function, placed over a `ak-mouse-over` and then `value` is value which you are passing to function.

```
<button ak-mouse-over="btnMouseOver(hValue)">
    Hello There !
</button>
```

Also you need to call `scope.$apply()` from `mouserover` event handler to keep of digest cycle as you are running an event outside angular context.

[**Demo here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/KL3d2AZybqnHibpOK8TB?p=preview)

Comment: So, basically if we are passing direct string value to attribute directive function, `{jValue: 'myValue'}` parent function should have called by passing string value - `'myValue'`. else script will keep looking for `value` (per my question).

Comment: @Avinash no.. I edited my answer.. basically if you wrote `ak-mouse-over="btnMouseOver(a)"` then directive call would have been `scope.mouseOver({ a: value });`.. understood? our `hValue` current value is `hValue` because is there present on attribute function paraemter

Comment: in my question I asked `ak-mouse-over="btnMouseOver('Win Win')"` so `'win win'` is string value, however per your updated comment `hValue` is parameter /variable name(not quoted). So angular will consider it (`hValue`) as scope variable of parent controller. Which I tested before asking this question. so if parent controller function called with string value, directive's scope function/event should called isolated method with json `{jValue: 'value'}'`.

Comment: @Avinash don't get confused...if you are directly passing string parameter in function `Win Win`, it wouldn't look what have passed from directive.. it will only just pass what ever there as hard code value.

Comment: Yes `'win win'` is hard coded value that I am passing to parent controller's `btnMouseOver` function. If I remove quotes I am getting error. So I have to use quotes around it and so in directive event JSON value `{jValue: 'value'}`.

If I call `ak-mouse-over="btnMouseOver(firstName)"` then `firstName` variable has to be in scope of parent controller.

 I tested both scenarios and working perfectly.

Comment: And I saw your demo, and you are passing value 'TEST' just from directive's event and not from HTML.

Comment: @Avinash when you had `firstName` like `btnMouseOver(firstName)`, it was working because it was trying to evaluate `firstName` value from scope variable, which it does.. but when you had `win win` value in function like `btnMouseOver(win win)` angular does tries to evaluate that expression inside angular scope & its gonna be fail because `win win` is not variable & then you will see error inside a console which would be `$pareser` error(as former rule, variable name don't have ` `space in it)

Comment: @Avinash I think you are violating/misunderstand why to use `&` in isolated scope.

Comment: @Avinash my dear friend, you can not have `$scope.firstName='';` outside a controller.. $scope is not present outside controller.. check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/dLEFdDip1abKBujk7zGF?p=preview) out

Comment: That I know buddy! didn't see controller properly. 
You got same code (`'win win'` & `firstName`) what I was looking for! Thanks !

Comment: @Avinash yes I got the `'Win win'` which I mentioned earlier..what is your problem.. what you don't understood?

Comment: I was clear about JSON format parameter passing to parent function (using isolated scope variables/`'@' OR '=' directive attributes`  and then send those scope variables thru JSON format to parent method). 

I was looking for how a hard coded value can be sent to parent controller's function, thru directive event, without using isolated scope. 

Modified [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/K9SWZmWGjgKEjPYhVF47?p=preview) which can achieve hard coded value and also controller's scope variable.